# What is error code 495 on Google Play and the YouTube app?

Tags: google-play-store, youtube

> "Facebook" could not be downloaded due to an error. (495)

How do I solve this error?

[image: Messenger Image]

Comment: Armed with google-fu, and searched yielded [this](http://androidforums.com/general-tablet-talk/503474-error-495-a.html) makes me wonder, is your clock out of sync completely, perhaps on the wifi network's router and not your device?

Comment: For reason unkown to me, I cannot add an answer, so I'll add a comment here then. I faced this same error while trying to update Facebook app, while few other apps updated just fine, while using mobile data. For a time I was wondering why Facebook refused to update, until I did remember that I had prevented several apps from using mobile data. One of them was "Media". After allowing it to use mobile data, Facebook updated just fine.

Comment: There is a helpful official 'Google Play' help page which boils down all the advice here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/troubleshooter/6332137 I'd post it as an answer but don't have the rep.

Answer (score 5):

According to a user on [The Transformers' Forum](http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-help/18816-unable-download-apps-google-play-error-495-a.html):

> *"I had the same problem but fixed it. Go to* `Settings - Apps- All- Download manager` *and Clear data. Then go to* `Settings - Apps - All - Google Play Store` *and Clear cache. Play Store should work and if not try restarting your device."*

There is [another answer](http://www.transformerforums.com/forum/asus-transformer-tf101-help/18816-unable-download-apps-google-play-error-495-a.html#post161141) that says that Uninstalling the updates of Google Play app and restarting the device and updating it again solved the issue,

> *"Uninstall all updates to Google Play, reverting to the original market, then re-starting that, and letting it re-update to Google Play, then re-starting it again."*

However vague, clearing the data on Google Play Store app might do the job.

Comment: I have tried but same error and my device works with other WIFI networks.

Comment: Wherefore occurs this error?

Comment: Can it be possible that the network you use is blocking downloads (or even the word "facebook") in some way or the other?

Answer (score 2):

I get this error myself, and it looks like this is mostly a network issue. May be because of some stale values on device, clearing application cache for Google Play or Download Manager can help.

However trying a different network (wifi instead of data) works for me. It might also help if you change DNS addresses on device, I guess.

```
D/Finsky  ( 4507): [1] DownloadImpl.setState: com.google.android.apps.books from DOWNLOADING to ERROR.
D/Finsky  ( 4507): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.onError:     com.google.android.apps.books: onError 495.
D/Finsky  ( 4507): [1] DownloadQueueImpl.remove: Download    com.google.android.apps.books removed from DownloadQueue
D/Finsky  ( 4507): [1] InstallerTask.cancelCleanup: Cancel running installation of com.google.android.apps.books
E/Finsky  ( 4507): [1] RestoreTracker.onInstallPackageEvent: Restore package com.google.android.apps.books download error 495
I/ElegantRequestDirector( 4507): I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
I/ElegantRequestDirector( 4507): Retrying request
```

Answer (score -1):

Had the problem on an Alcatel device where "all apps" in settings - apps does not exist. Using WLAN instead of 3g for downloading from Play Store worked. Not sure if it will now also work again on 3g.