# Clear Download cache on Alcatel devices?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, cache

I am using an Alcatel 997D with Android 4.0.4. I need to clear the Download cache, the normal way to do this is to go to Settings - Apps - all apps, then select Download and then clear cache. However on my 997D, there is no "all apps" in Settings - Apps!?

Any hint on alternative ways to clear the download cache? I need this [to fix error code 495](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23055/what-is-error-code-495-on-google-play-and-the-youtube-app) on Google Play Store.

Comment: On some of my devices I also hat trouble locating the "all apps" tab. Have you tried "swiping" right-to-left when in *Settings->Apps->Manage Apps*? I saw more than one Android user surprised when I did that on their devices ;)

Comment: Yes, I did that, actually it's also not my only device, so I am aware of this - thanks for the hint though. I meanwhile could fix the 495 problem (see linked thread), still wondering how one could clear the download cache though.

Comment: Hard to say, if you cannot access the full list of apps. But the playstore holds several alternative app-managers. There must be one also allowing you to access the app data for that.

Comment: hmm, you are right, that's an alternative I didn't think of. Ironity of this is that downloading anything from play store didn't work and the fix for this would have been to clear the cache ;-) Anyway, one could maybe download an .apk manually and install it. Still wondering if there's a way with system provided applcations.

Comment: Ouch, yes. Like with the "insufficient memory" error you could cure with a system/cache cleaner if you could install it... If you find something, be welcome to answer your own question! Guess you're not the only one wishing to know :)