# Google Play Error Code: 495 on Android One

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat

I am using an Android One mobile phone. When I try to install apps via WiFi I get Error Code: 495, but, when I do the same via mobile data it's working fine.

When  follow the procedure mentioned in [What is error code 495 on Google Play and the YouTube app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23055/what-is-error-code-495-on-google-play-and-the-youtube-app) I get a "Connection Time Out Error". If I try a second time I can see the "Installing..." indicator appear, but I don't see any downloading file information and finally I get the same Error Code: 495.

What could be the problem? How to solve this issue?

Comment: @DanHulme, Before i have posted this question i had seen the question what you have mentioned and the mentioned solution is not solved my problem. FYKI, I'm using #androidone mobile phone and installed os version 4.4.4kitkat

Comment: [Edit] your question and say what you've already tried, and what happened.

Comment: @DanHulme, i updated my question. please look into that